# How to work with powerpoint in php?

Tags: php, powerpoint

I would like to know the best way to work with powepoint slides in php,

Is there an api or some reading material to undesrtand how to extract the slides into different images? If yes, is there anyway to capture the animations?

Comment: Closing this topic seems an improper response.  This entire website does nothing but help people trying to code solutions. This person simply asked for help coding. The response below seems proper and no spam was added. Marking it as closed seems inordinately inappropriate and unhelpful.  In the future, use better judgement or consult others before arbitrarily assigning a good question to a closed status.

Comment: This question is from 4 years before most of the people asking for the close as off-topic were even on stackoverflow.


At that time there weren't many tools nor information on the topic.



if you check the answer that I accepted it says that the tool he provided was pretty straight forward but didn't have any documentation

Maybe they want to start closing old posts, but the answer is still good and the tool is now on github and constantly updated for what I checked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have always used [phppowerpoint](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/), it's pretty straight forward although it lacks documentation and you might not be able to render animations

Comment: Does this works with ppts older than 2007? Had you ever tryied with ppt 97?

Comment: Not at present... PHPPowerPoint is an "in memory" representation of a presentation of the object, that can be written to file using an extensible writer system. At the moment, the only writer that's been developed is the pptx writer. Other writers for different formats, such as ppt, could be written by anybody (that's a big benefit of open source), and then plugged into that extensible writer system - only problem is that nobody beside the core developers ever contributes new writers to the project - and the core developers don't have time to do everything that other people want them to do

Comment: Just lacks the support of templates.

Comment: @MarkBaker is it possible to write Powerpoint Charts which are editable inside Office Powerpoint ?

Comment: hi need some minimal example code to use PHPPowerpoint classes, im struggling to use tat class in my php page, because i cant find any code document in source. can you please..