# Parsing powerpoint into one Image per slide

Tags: parsing, image-processing, webserver, powerpoint

I would like to convert a powerpoint presentation into a series of images. One per slide specifically so they can be uploaded as an image gallery to a blog.  Does anyone know of any libraries that can convert a .ppt into images.  Any language is fine as long as it can run on a *nix server, so no C# or .Net dependent libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if one existed, and I would guess one does, it can't address animations in a meaningful way.  I see more and more ppt presentations making good use of animations to get their points across.  Many of these animations will overlap one another.  How could such a slide be turned into a single image?  How would you prioritize which animated image segments should overlap the others?  You may want to keep an eye on this thread: [Converting ppt to png using Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214950/657003)

This might get you a solution via php [How to work with powerpoint in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072664/how-to-work-with-powerpoint-in-php)

This might work with python: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4995877/657003

This is a good discussion of the problem you face: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Comment: Awesome answers I will check them all out. As for animations, the application I am developing will not utilize animations at this point so the slides designed for it will not use ppt animations. So, it's a non issue